# Как вызвать handle и поменять состояние родителького компонента из дочерних?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

У меня есть страница (компонент) Home, находится в файле Home.js. В этом файле объявляю состояние scroll, вот так:

```
let [scroll, setScroll] = useState({ offset: 0, currentsectionIndex: 0 });
setScroll = ({ ...newScroll }) => {
        scroll.offset = newScroll.offset
        scroll.currentsectionIndex = newScroll.index

}
```

В файле Home.js также есть несколько handle функций:

```
    const handleScroll = () => {...}
    const handleClick = (e) => {...}
```

Три точки - пропущенный код. В return блоке есть компоненты поменьше:

```
return (
    
let sectionClasses = dataItem.isReverced ? "section section__reverced" : "section";
                    return <DatabaseSection titles={dataItem.titles} subtitles={dataItem.subtitles} key={dataItem.id} bgImg={dataItem.bgImg} classes={sectionClasses} description={dataItem.description} delete_menu_id={dataItem.id} text_id={dataItem.text_id} actions={actions} bgvideo={dataItem.bgvideo}></DatabaseSection>

...
)
```

А в DatabaseSection есть еще один компонент - span со ссылками, при клике на ссылку нужно вызывать `handleClick` и менять состояние `scroll`, но проблема в том, что состояние и `handle` находятся в другом файле.

Есть ли возможность импортировать state и handleClick в Home и в компоненты поменьше? Или придется вешать `handleClick` на `Home` и получать доступ к элементу по которому кликнули через несколько `e.target?`

То есть структура такая. Хочу кликнуть на `Home (state, handleClick) -> DatabaseSection -> span_menu -> Link.onClick(handleClick)` А в `handleClick` вызываем `setScroll`. Как мне в самом последнем компоненте Link использовать handleClick из компонента Home?

Comment: Зачем переобъявлять `setScroll`?

Comment: @ksa чтобы state обновлялся моментально. Так, если передать в setScroll новый объект без переопределения, то scroll не обновится сразу.

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятно зачем тебе вообще стейт...

Comment: @ksa В state хранится текущий индекс секции сайта. Нужен для постраничного скролла. Вопрос в том, как поменять этот state при клике на компонент, который находится в другом файле.

Comment: Давай определимся что такое стейт... Нам нужно получить от `useState()` два ключевых элемента - собственно стейт и функцию, которая его будет менять. Только в такой "комплектации" Реакт будет реагировать на изменение стейта. Ты же сделал свою функцию, которая якобы будет менять стейт. Вот только для Реакта это филькина грамота и он на такую функцию вообще никак не будет реагировать. Всякие дальнейшие твои действия бесполезны.

Comment: @ksa как не будет реагировать, если при скролле с такой функцией объект scroll изменяется? Я его в консоль вывожу, все работает. Могу скрин добавить.

Comment: Если бы все работало как нужно - ты бы тут не спрашивал "как поменять состояние". ;) Стейт должна менять "стейтовая" функция, а не твоя "самописная". От того что ты сам курочишь стейтовую переменную Реакту не холодно, не жарко. Он вообще не в курсе что стейт кто-то поменял, поскольку "стейтовую" функцию никто не вызывал. Ты ведь ее переопределил...

Comment: @ksa Хорошо, что предлагаете? Как переписать? Я спрашивал, как state импортировать и использовать (менять) в дочерних компонентах. Из Home переменная scroll у меня меняется. Брал идею, как менять отсюда https://medium.com/ableneo/react-setstate-does-not-immediately-update-the-state-84dbd26f67d5

Comment: Родительский стейт в дочерних компонентах меняется соответствующей "стейтовой" функцией, которую нужно передать дочкам пропсами или контекстом.